# Adding other libraries in React.js app

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am adding [image slider library](http://previous.themepunch.com/revolution/liveguide/01.Sample-Boxed.html) in my react app. It is working but I am not sure whether it is the only way or not.

Inside my react.js file, I did this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script= document.createElement('script');
    script.type= 'text/javascript';
    script.src= 'js/banner.js';
    head.appendChild(script);
}
```

and in the `banner.js` file I have added the code for slider 
and the code for library is added in `index.html` file as a **script tag**. I know it is adding the js file multiple times but i don't know another way to add it
It is working absolutely fine but I am not sure it is the right way

Comment: Why don't you add the js file directly to your html file?

Comment: No. You should include libraries normally through npm and import, and follow this guide to use non-react libs in your components https://github.com/ryanflorence/react-training/blob/gh-pages/lessons/05-wrapping-dom-libs.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Andy's comment is correct, you should include your libraries through `npm` when possible. To do this, google the package to find it's name in the npm registry.

You can then run `npm install --save banner` (assuming the package name you found is `banner`) to automatically save the library to your `package.json`. This way any time you run `npm install` or `npm update`, the package will be taken care of via `npm`.

In your `.jsx` file where you create your React component, you can add this to the very top:

```
// if you're not using ES6
const banner = require('banner') 
// if you are
import * as banner from 'banner';
// if the package exports modules
import {banner} from 'banner';
```

If the library doesn't exist as a package on the `npm` registry, you can still do this in pretty much the same way. You will just need to add the `.js` file for the library to your project and use a relative path to `require`/`import` (i.e. `require('../../vendor/banner.js')`).

Comment: Wow... I totally forgot to mention; this method, if used for the web, needs to be coupled with a bundling/packaging phase. Be sure to look into some sort of task runner like Grunt or Gulp, or - my personal favorite - Webpack! If you just require/import scripts, they will not be included in the public page by default. Webpack can be used to crawl through your code and inject all of the dependencies of your project into one or many files (depending on how you define your Webpack config).